What is the meaning of py -m pip?
I have installed python 3.12.1, pip.
To install any module I have to use pip in below format.
c:>/Users/Admin> py -m pip install camelcase
c:>/Users/Admin> py -m pip install panda

Whats the use of py and -m and what does it stands for?
Previously i used just command pip install but now using
C>/py -m pip install pandas

why there is change and when these has been done.
why the below command shows an error?
C:\Users\Admin>pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.


This question is similar to: Difference between pip3 and python3 -m pip. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also  What is the purpose of the -m switch?

Note that you have just installed python 3.12 but the error is about python 3.10 which is likely your prior version of python. You may need to open a new prompt and/or ensure that python 3.12 is on your path ahead of or in replace of 3.10

First, You Need To KNow That EVERY Python Module Which Is Executable With the CMD (not only like import pip pip ..., simpler explanation is the modules who have an init folder), And PIP is a python module, Also To Run A Module You Use py / python -m <module name> [params] SO py -m pip install pygame is the same thing as: pip install pygame , the py -m really just spends 1s of your life if you have python in PATH so just use the short option.
